# Make one AngularJS directive add another directive to the DOM on click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one AngularJS directive that creates a button.

When this button is clicked, I want to add another AngularJS directive (component) to the page.

How do I do this?

**Directive for my "create a post" button:**

```
myApp.directive('newPostButton', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind("click", function(){
        alert("HI!");
      });
    },
    template: '<button>New Post</button>'
  };
}]);
```

**Directive for my "post composer" element, that appears when "create a post" is clicked:**

```
myApp.directive('postComposer', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind("click", function(){
        alert("POSTED!");
      });
    },
    template: '<div><textarea placeholder="Write a new post"></textarea><button>Post</button>'
  };
}]);
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to have the directive modify DOM outside of its element tree. It's probably better to have a higher-level directive `post` that organizes child directives like `newPostButton` and `postComposer`. (Is there even a real need for `newPostButton` to be a directive?)

Comment: I think Angular doesn't like DOM manipulation the way JQuery would do. You'd have to create a condition that triggers the component, and then change the condition on the button click. The simplest way would be ngShow - but you might have to use something else depending on your specific need.

Comment: @Donny-P mark something as answer if it is correct. That's how stackoverflow works!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question but as @New Dev and @Gratus D. stated, maybe "jQueryish" DOM manipulation is not the best road to take, and maybe `new-post-button` shouldn't be directive at all.

Instead, you could combine your directives and just toggle visibility of your "composer", maybe?

Something like...

[image: imgur]

Usage would be as simple as

```
<post-composer callback="vm.add(post)"></post-composer>
```

Directive itself

```
/**
 * Compose a new post
 * @param  {Function} callback fn
 * @return {Object}   post
 * @return {String}   post.title
 * @return {String}   post.content
 */
app.directive('postComposer', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      callback: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      function reset() {
        scope.isComposing = false;
        scope.content = null;
      }

      scope.submit = function() {
        var post = { title: 'new title', content: scope.content };
        scope.callback({ post: post });
        reset();
        //$.notify('Submitted', 'success');
      };

      scope.cancel = function() {
        reset();       
        //$.notify('Canceled', 'warn');
      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'post-composer-tpl.html'
  }; 
});
```

Where And the HTML template

```
<!-- new post -->
<div ng-show="!isComposing">
  <button type="button" 
          class="btn btn-default"
          ng-click="isComposing = !isComposing">
          New post
  </button>
</div>
<!-- compose -->
<div ng-show="isComposing">
  <textarea class="form-control" 
            ng-model="content"
            placeholder="Write a new post..."></textarea>
  <button type="button" 
          class="btn btn-default"
          ng-click="cancel()">
          Cancel
  </button>
  <button type="button" 
          class="btn btn-default"
          ng-disabled="!content"
          ng-click="submit()">
          Submit
  </button>
</div>
```

Related Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/zI6plp

Comment: Beautiful answer! This should definetly be marked as the correct and best answer! Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

You can append compiled directive where its needed in click handler:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('newPostButton', ['$compile',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("click", function() {
          angular.element(document.body).append($compile("<div data-post-composer></div>")(scope));
        });
      },
      template: '<button>New Post</button>'
    };
  }
]);

myApp.directive('postComposer', ['$compile',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("click", function() {
          alert("POSTED!");
        });
      },
      template: '<div><textarea placeholder="Write a new post"></textarea><button>Post</button>'
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-new-post-button></div>
</section>
```